# Grails error validating on existing input

Tags: java, grails, grails-orm

I got this error when I tried to modify my Controller (generated by scaffolding).
What I want to do, is to add current user that I capture from SpringSecurity Service.

Payment class has User property inside. 
I tried to inject the user value from `springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()`;

When I tried this, it will produce error : 
*Property [user] of class [class kks.Payment] cannot be null*

I tried to debug, it looks fine but still producing this error ....

This will work well if I put user.id inside the form as hidden value .. but I didn't want do this ...

How to solve this problem ?

Here is my code:

```
class PaymentController {

    def springSecurityService;

    @Transactional
    def save(Payment PaymentInstance) {
        println("1..... Payment");
        PaymentInstance.user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser();
        if (PaymentInstance == null) {
            notFound()
            return
        }

        println("2..... Payment"+springSecurityService.getCurrentUser().class);
        println(PaymentInstance.user.id); // still okay !!! 

        if (PaymentInstance.hasErrors()) {
            println("3..... hasErrors?"); // entered here with  Property [user] of class > [class kks.Payment] cannot be null

            respond PaymentInstance.errors, view: 'create'
            return
        }


        println("3..... Payment");
        PaymentInstance.save flush: true

        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: >[message(code: 'Payment.label',
                                        default: 'Payment'), PaymentInstance.id])
                redirect PaymentInstance
            }
            '*' { respond PaymentInstance, [status: CREATED] }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: What's the result from `springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()`?

Comment: it return the User class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inserting value in the `paymentInstance` you should validate the instance like:

```
paymentInstance.user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser();
paymentInstance.validate()
```

and then check for error.

PS: Please follow convention: variable name should be started from lower case character.

Comment: Thanks ... it Works ! I use lowercase char for var ... but I just copy paste and replace the name into english (since the var in another lang .. so I forgot to turn the var name into lower case)